# How to mock HttpContext in a ShoppingCart controller/model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

In our MVC4 application with Entity Framework 4.0 based on the [Music Store Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-8) we are using Moq to mock the `DbContext` and unit test are logic. One of our methods proves difficult to test though since it makes use of `HttpContext` or `HttpContextBase`. One example method looks like this:

```
public static ShoppingCart GetCart(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        var cart = new ShoppingCart();
        cart.ShoppingCartId = cart.GetCartId(context);
        return cart;
    }
```

The only property collected from `HttpContextBase` is the `[CartSessionKey]` as can be seen here:

```
public string GetCartId(HttpContextBase context)
{
    if (context.Session[CartSessionKey] == null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(context.User.Identity.Name))
        {
            context.Session[CartSessionKey] =
                context.User.Identity.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            // Generate a new random GUID using System.Guid class
            Guid tempCartId = Guid.NewGuid();
            // Send tempCartId back to client as a cookie
            context.Session[CartSessionKey] = tempCartId.ToString();
        }
    }
    return context.Session[CartSessionKey].ToString();
}
```

We have heard horror stories that `HttpContext` is a very complex class and that if you print it you have enough paper to circle the earth eight times.

Nevertheless we want to mock it. The question is how. The properties that we want to mock are the `[CartSessionKey]`, and the property that come from the context as `contest.User.Identity.Name`.

We suspect we need to use something like this:

```
        var mockData = new Mock<FakeContext>();
        mockData.Setup(m => m.Orders).Returns(memoryOrderItems);
        mockData.Setup(m => m.Carts).Returns(memoryCartItems);

        Mock<HttpContextBase> mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        Mock<HttpRequestBase> mockHttpRequest = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();

        mockHttpRequest.Setup(x => x.CartSessionKey).Returns(1);
        mockHttpContext.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(mockHttpRequest.Object);
```

but we cannot find how to specifically implement this so we do not get any errors on methods that use `context.Session[CartSessionKey]` or `context.User.Identity.Name`.

We hope someone can help us out.

/edit

When we do this:

```
 var memoryUserItems = new FakeDbSet<User>()
        {
            new User { Email = "test@test.de",
                       FullName = "Test Person",
                       isAvailable = true,
                       Name = "WHat"
            },
            new User { Email = "test2@test.de",
                       FullName = "Test Person 2",
                       isAvailable = true,
                       Name = "WHat 2"
            }
        };
 (...) Other memory...Items
```

And then this:

```
        // Create mock units of work
        var mockData = new Mock<FakeContext>();
        mockData.Setup(m => m.Orders).Returns(memoryOrderItems);
        mockData.Setup(m => m.Carts).Returns(memoryCartItems);
        mockData.Setup(m => m.Users).Returns(memoryUserItems);

        var principalMock = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
        var identityMock = new Mock<IIdentity>();
        var userMock = 
        identityMock.Setup(x => x.Name).Returns("Test!");
        identityMock.Setup(x => x.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true); // optional ;)
        mockData.Setup(x => x.Identity).Returns(identityMock.Object);
        var httpReqBase = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>(); // this is useful if you want to test Ajax request checks or cookies in the controller.
        var httpContextBase = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();

        httpContextBase.Setup(x => x.User).Returns(principalMock.Object);
        httpContextBase.Setup(x => x.Session[It.IsAny<string>()]).Returns(1); //Here is the session indexer. You can swap 'any' string for specific string.
        httpContextBase.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(httpReqBase.Object);
```

We get the error that:

> Error 3   'project.Models.FakeContext' does
>   not contain a definition for 'Identity' and no extension method
>   'Identity' accepting a first argument of type
>   'project.Models.FakeContext' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

/ edit2

To make it more clear. The actual method I am testing is the following:

```
    public ActionResult Complete(int id)
    {
        // Make sure that user is currentuser and otherwise bring user to our Thief page
        if (id != db.GetCurrentUserId())
        {
            return View("Thief");
        }

        var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
        var currentDate = DateTime.Today;
        var viewModel = new ShoppingCartViewModel
        {
            CartItems = cart.GetCartItems(),
            CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(),
            ProductItems = db.Products.ToList()
        };

        if (viewModel.CartItems.Count() == 0)
        {
            return View("Empty");
        }

        // Try to write cart to order table
        try
        {
            foreach (var item in viewModel.CartItems)
            {
                ProcessOrder(item, id, currentDate);

            }
            // after this we empty the shopping cart
            cart.EmptyCart();
            return View();
        }
        catch
        {
            // Invalid - display error page
            return View("Error");
        }

    }
```

As can be seen the `var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);` uses `this.HttpContext`. In the test I just do `controller.Complete(1)`. I cannot pass a new `HttpContext` to the controller I guess?

/ edit 3

While using the code below with the mocks I get the following message:

```
Test Name:  TestCheckoutCompleteShouldWithEmptyCart
Test FullName:  Controllers.CheckoutControllerTest.TestCheckoutCompleteShouldWithEmptyCart
Test Source:    Controllers\CheckoutControllerTest.cs : line 141
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.0158591

Result Message: 
Test method Controllers.CheckoutControllerTest.TestCheckoutCompleteShouldWithEmptyCart threw exception: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Result StackTrace:  
at Models\ShoppingCart.cs:line 170
   at \Models\ShoppingCart.cs:line 20
   at \Controllers\CheckoutController.cs:line 48
   at Controllers\CheckoutControllerTest.cs:line 143
```

Comment: Are you testing public string GetCartId(HttpContextBase context) method? What's your MUT ? GetCart or GetCartId?

Comment: Hi @Spock, what is a MUT? `GetCartId` is the main concern since the `GetCart` depends on that.

Comment: Sorry it is the Method Under Test. It is pretty easy what you trying to achieve. See my answer also there are few other ways of doing it. Happy to help

Comment: I think testing the public GetCartId you get more value than testing the GetCart as it hardly has much behavior at all.

Comment: @Spock the point is that this method is used by a lot of other methods (that I want to test) and they break on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here it goes. The following works in MVC5 with AD, I'm not sure if it's fully backwards compatible, you'll have to check.

```
var principalMock = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
var identityMock = new Mock<IIdentity>();
identityMock.Setup(x => x.Name).Returns("Test!");
identityMock.Setup(x => x.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true); // optional ;)
userMock.Setup(x => x.Identity).Returns(identityMock.Object);
var httpReqBase = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>(); // this is useful if you want to test Ajax request checks or cookies in the controller.
var httpContextBase = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();

httpContextBase.Setup(x => x.User).Returns(principalMock.Object);
httpContextBase.Setup(x => x.Session[It.IsAny<string>()]).Returns(1); //Here is the session indexer. You can swap 'any' string for specific string.
httpContextBase.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(httpReqBase.Object);
```

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the question for a new issue that came up with the `userMock` object. Could you explain how to make the `x.Identity` part work?

Comment: @user2609980 How does your `FakeContext` look like? Does it use `IIdentity`?

Comment: It consists of `public virtual IDbSet`s for each `Model` (e.g., `public virtual IDbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }` and two empty methods like  `public int SaveChanges()
        {
            return 1;
        }` and 

        `public void Dispose()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }`  So, it does not use `IIdentity`. Should we?

Comment: @user2609980 You probably shouldn't. I don't know why you're setting up the data mock with `IIdentity` here: `mockData.Setup(x => x.Identity).Returns(identityMock.Object);`. You probably should remove it... :)

Comment: Yes I did. Unfortunately when using the code as above without the `Identity` part, I still get that `HttpContextBase context` is null.

Comment: @user2609980 If you pass the mocked `httpContextBase.Object` as a parameter, it should work just fine...

Comment: The point is that I test another method that takes an int as a parameter. That method uses the `HttpContext` in the `GetCart` method.

Comment: The `Controller.HttpContext` under test should pass the mocked `HttpContext` as a parameter. As in `Controllers.Controller.HttpContext`, since the method takes a `this.HttpContext` where `this` is the controller.

Comment: @user2609980 Then you should set up the mock for `HttpContextBase` properly, because that's the class that's exposed by `HttpContext` property. I'm not sure what you mean by 'passing new HttpContext to the controller', because it doesn't really make much sense...

Comment: In your code we set up the mock for `HttpContextBase` right? With passing the new `HttpContext` to the controller I mean that the Controller under test has access to the (fake) `HttpContext`, can use its values and does not give a null reference exception. I do not know how to get our new ` httpContextBase.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(httpReqBase.Object);` to be actually used.

Comment: Then you can set the controller's `ControllerContext` to a new instance, and the constructor of `ControllerContext` takes `HttpContextBase` as one of the parameters - as far as I remember.

Comment: Aha, so the controller has its own `ControllerContext`... So I need to change that constructor to also take the fake `HttpContextBase`? :) Thanks for the answers btw!

Comment: @user2609980 Yup! Also, funnily enough, `ControllerContext` takes a dependency on a `Controller`, and that controller can have the context set to the `ControllerContext`. A bit of a circular dependency, but that's how it is :)

Comment: Last question: where do I find this `ControllerContext`? :-) Or should I create one myself?

Comment: @user2609980 [It's a class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllercontext%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), you only have to instantiate it. Then you can [set it in a `Controller` instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.controllercontext%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This would help you to write a proper Unit Test using Moq.

```
[TestClass]
public class SutTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetCartId_WhenUserNameIsNotNull_SessionContainsUserName()
    {
        var httpContextStub = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        var httpSessionStub = new Mock<ISessionSettings>();
        httpSessionStub.Setup(x => x.Get<string>(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(() => null);

        httpSessionStub.SetupSequence(x => x.Get<string>(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns(null)
            .Returns("FakeName");

        var httpUserStub = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
        var httpIdenttyStub = new Mock<IIdentity>();
        httpUserStub.SetupGet(x => x.Identity).Returns(httpIdenttyStub.Object);
        httpIdenttyStub.SetupGet(x => x.Name).Returns("FakeName");

        httpContextStub.Setup(x => x.User).Returns(httpUserStub.Object);
        var sut = new Sut(httpSessionStub.Object);

        var result = sut.GetCartId(httpContextStub.Object);

        Assert.AreEqual("FakeName",result );
    }
}
```

Check the SetupSequence method which gives you find Control over different values being return on he same stubbed call.
Also important to decouple your session from HttpContext as you can always run into issues.

```
public class SessionSettings : ISessionSettings
{
    private readonly HttpSessionStateBase _session;
    public SessionSettings(HttpSessionStateBase session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }

    public T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        return (T)_session[key];
    }

    public void Set<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        _session[key] = value;
    }
}

public interface ISessionSettings
{
    T Get<T>(string key);
    void Set<T>(string key, T value);
}

public class Sut
{
    private ISessionSettings _sessionSettings;
    public Sut(ISessionSettings sessionSettings)
    {
        _sessionSettings = sessionSettings;
    }
    public string GetCartId(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        if (_sessionSettings.Get<string>(CartSessionKey) == null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(context.User.Identity.Name))
            {
                _sessionSettings.Set<string>(CartSessionKey, context.User.Identity.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                // Generate a new random GUID using System.Guid class
                Guid tempCartId = Guid.NewGuid();
                // Send tempCartId back to client as a cookie
                _sessionSettings.Set<string>(CartSessionKey, tempCartId.ToString());
            }
        }
        return _sessionSettings.Get<string>(CartSessionKey);
    }

    private string CartSessionKey = "key";
}
```

This way the code is more readable and easier to understand.